# Handling Visibility of View in RecyclerView.onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am making a chat App, for this app I am using RecyclerView (As this is efficient then ListView). I am facing issue regarding handling the View's visibility. My idea is, whenever I have a new message. The item which is representing that Message, should have some bar at left. Below is the xml layout I am using for an item of RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View 
        android:id="@+id/vwLeftLine"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imvwImage"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_size"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/vwLeftLine"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_size"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imvwImage"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imvwImage"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLastMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imvwImage"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imvwImage"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Last Message" />
```

Below is the Adapter I am using:

```
package com.zai.recylerviewtest;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ItemsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemHolder>{

    private ArrayList<Item> items;

    public ItemsAdapter(ArrayList<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemHolder holder, int position) {
        Item item = items.get(position);

        holder.txtName.setText(item.name);
        holder.txtLastMessage.setText(item.lastMessage);

        holder.vwLeftLine.setVisibility(item.isNewMessage ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }


    @Override
    public ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup group, int type) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(group.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_items, null); 
        return new ItemHolder(v);
    }

    public static class Item {
        public String name;
        public String lastMessage;
        public boolean isNewMessage;
    }
}
```

And this is ViewHolder

```
package com.zai.recylerviewtest;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ItemHolder extends ViewHolder{

    public View vwLeftLine;
    public TextView txtName;
    public TextView txtLastMessage;

    public ItemHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        vwLeftLine = itemView.findViewById(R.id.vwLeftLine);
        txtName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        txtLastMessage = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtLastMessage);
    }   
}
```

Now As you can see in Adapter, I am setting Visibility Of `vwLeftLine` according to `isNewMessage`. But I am getting this:

[image]

As you can see, the line which has new message (which has `vwLeftLine` visibility to `VISIBLE`) is a little more margin then others, so `vwLeftLine` is taking space but its not visible.

Thanx in Advance.

Thanx in advance